# How to use Asterisk build a telephony system with one land line and two cell phone numbers?

Tags: telephony, asterisk, cellular

I think I am on the same boat like many others: My family has a land line from my local telephony company and we have two cell phones (lines) as well. We live in a two-story home.

I am considering unifying three phone numbers by using Asterisk. I want a PBX such that:

1) It supports multiple extensions so that I can make internal/intercom call or transfer call to another extension easily

2) The two cell phone lines can be *converted* to land line alike service and I can connect them to FXO ports. So I will have three, instead of one incoming line.

3) When a person calls me, depending on which number he is calling, there are different ringtones. But I can always use any handset to answer the call.

4) The land line will be the default phone line when I place an outbound call. If the land line is busy, I can choose to use cell phone number #1 or cell phone number #2 to make a call. I do not want to use cell phone to make a call. Instead, I want to use regular VOIP phone handset to place a call.

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: I found this product: http://www.myxlink.com/xlink_bttn.aspx It is great!

Comment: With Asterisk - 1 and 3 are feasible. 2 and 4 will needs extra hardware.

Comment: Would you please tell me what kind of hardware is needed? Thanks.

Comment: That xlink you linked would be one possible solution. I don't know of any others off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: A quick google gave me this - http://www.stocksy.co.uk/articles/Networks/use_an_old_mobile_phone_as_a_gsm_gateway_in_asterisk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need find voip phone with changable ringtone.

Simplest variant is cisco 7940/7960 used phone(30-50usd each)

After that you need have in all places where you put phone ethernet (local network)

Need have router, server for asterisk

For connect landline you need have fxo sip addapter, for gsm you need gsm sip gate or usb dongle supported by chan_dongle. I not recomend use phone as described in article above, will be alot of issues.

After that you need install PBX in Aflash distro on you server and setup outbound and inbound trunks acordinly to rules above.

Sure you need very special knowledge or need hire expert for that.

For start i recommend you read ORelly's book "Asterisk the future of telephony"